# How do I make an GameObject Instantiated from a prefab spawn some particles?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

I would like this object to spawn some nice particles when destroyed.
I did this:

```cs
[SerializeField] GameObject boom;

//↓ in void update, where it checks if it has 0 hp
GameObject explode = Instantiate(boom, transform.position, transform.rotation);
```

That wont work, as I cannot drag and drop the particle system into the inspector, it wont work, because prefabs are not stored in the scene. What do i do instead?

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Well you  kinda need a particle system per dying thing most likely. So you could find the particle on object start and clone it on destroy and play it

Comment: Change the type of boom to ParticleSystem instead of GameObject, that way you have access to the functions of ParticleSystem.  Create a prefab using that ParticleSystem by dragging it into the Assets folder like usual.

Comment: @hijinxbassist What function do i use then with my new particle system thats not a gameobject anymore?

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you are asking, but I will attempt to answer.  ParticleSystem has functions you might find useful, like Play and Stop.  You can still access the GameObject by using `myParticleSystem.gameObject`.  I find it best to use the type you expect to deal with the most. eg. If you want to manually start playback on a particle system, it doesnt make much sense to use GameObject because you need to now add GetComponent to get the proper reference.  You can Instantiate the prefab the same way, because Instantiate accepts any object that inherits UnityEngine.Object.

Comment: You add them directly in code. It is the simplest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want the instantiated object to instantiate a particle effect when it dies? You could instead just make the particle effect a prefab and child the particle effect to the object so it is already in place when the object is instantiated. And then just call `myParticleEffect.Play()` when the object dies.

Seems like it may save you some time and effort if you simplify things.

For more on playing, pausing, stopping, e.t.c particle effects, check out the Unity Docs [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Play.html).